# How I can parse html source in website where it check javascript enable?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, parsing

Before Questioning, Sorry for my English.

While I constructing `Java Source` to parse web and extract attribute tag from html source, I found some websites where they embeded ads in their `WebPage` and they make client redirect to warning page when We disabled `JAVASCRIPT` option.
I think This Because when We disabled the javascript option, Some ads working on `Javascript` is not appear.

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
<script>vars={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></html>
```

If someone know How I can enable javascript on android java or prevent redirecting, Help!

Comment: Clearly they don't want you scraping their Web content.  Did you consider asking their support team for how to consume their data?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think that's right. but isn't there a way to scape webpage with enable javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It's a protection against ddos, web crawling and other such things…

Unless they provide you the real host u are unable to get the desired output…

When u try to web crawl a specific link, if they are using these, it means they are not showing their page directly, rather they are showing a dummy html (which you are getting as output) and that script is later redirecting to the real page blocking you… ☺️